# What is the meaning of "tramp asleep"?

Tags: word-meaning

I have just come across the following sentence on *The Sun*:

> A neighbour said: “I heard a whomp so I went to look out the window. At first I thought it was a **tramp asleep**. He had all his clothes on and everything.”

I checked all the possible dictionary entries for these two words, yet I cannot make head or tail of it. Could someone please explain to me what it means here?

Here is a link to the [source article](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/9417223/sunbather-stowaway-fell-3500ft-kenya-airways-jet-shock/).

Comment: "A tramp asleep" is a short of "a tramp fallen asleep."

Answer (score 4):

A **Tramp** is a person with no home, job, or money who travels around and asks for money from other people. Synonymous to a homeless person but tends to be a slightly more derogatory word [Ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/tramp)

**Asleep** is the you are not awake. I.e. He is sleeping -  the resting state in which the body is not active and the mind is unconscious. [Ref.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sleep)

In the the article, the neighbour thought that a homeless person was sleeping outside the window, it was later when she realised that it was the boy.

Answer (score 1):

The word *tramp* here is a noun, and means:

> **[tramp](https://www.wordnik.com/words/tramp)** (*n.*) one who travels aimlessly about on foot, doing odd jobs or begging for a living; an idle vagrant or homeless vagabond. (Wordnik)

So, "At first I thought it was a **tramp asleep**," means, "At first I thought it was a **sleeping homeless person**."